# Android java gradle Build

Tags: android

While trying to update the 3 years old project getting the following error. Is there any way to solve this issue.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15
> Could not find com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/27.0.1-jre/guava-27.0.1-jre.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15 > com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.4
> Could not find com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15 > com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.4
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15 > com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.4

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Did you find anything on this issue ?

Comment: Any update on this? Even I am trying the update my old project and now I am receiving this exact error message while trying to build the project.